Asymptotic behavior of a recursion
Let $x_n(0)=1$,
$$
x_n(N+1) = \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{k=0}^N \sum_{j=1}^n x_j(k)x_{n+1-j}(N-k) + \frac{10}{N+1} x_{n+1}(N) , \quad\quad N\ge 0 .
$$
So the recursion is on $N$, and at each level, we compute all $x_n(N)$, $n\ge 1$, before continuing. The question is whether
$$
\limsup_{N\to\infty} \left( x_1(N) \right)^{1/N} < \infty .
$$
Numerical results would also be appreciated, and maybe a CAS could be useful here also.

Consider the generating function:
$$F(z,t) := \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{N\geq0} x_n(N) z^{n-1} t^N.$$
Then $F(z,0)=\frac1{1-z}$ and
$$\frac\partial{\partial t} F(z,t) = F(z,t)^2 + 10F(z,t).$$
Solving this differential equation, we get
$$F(z,t) = \frac{10}{(11-10z)e^{-10t} - 1}$$
and thus
$$F(0,t) = \frac{10}{11e^{-10t} - 1}.$$

Now,
\begin{split}
x_1(N) &= [t^N]\ F(0,t) = [t^N]\ \frac{1}{1 + \frac{11}{10}(e^{-10t}-1)} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^N [t^N]\ \left(-\frac{11}{10}\right)^k(e^{-10t}-1)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^N \left\{ N\atop k\right\} \frac{k!}{N!} (-10)^{N-k} 11^k.
\end{split}
Bounding Stirling numbers of second kind from the above, we have
\begin{split}
x_1(N) &\leq \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{(-10)^{N-k} 11^k}{(N-k)!}
&\approx 11^N e^{-10/11}
\end{split}
implying that
$$\limsup_{N\to\infty} \left( x_1(N) \right)^{1/N} < 11.$$

Something is definitely not right with your line after "Now," -- the terms in your sum do not even tend to $0$... Perhaps it should have $k!$ in the denominator instead?

Yes, there is clearly a glitch in my expansion. I'll fix it later.

@ChristianRemling but I would assume that you know that for an analytic function defined in some ball around $0$, the radius of convergence is at least the radius of said ball...

And the radius of convergence is exactly $\frac{\log(11)}{10}$.

Well, can't we just turn the proof on its head? Let us define the function $F(z, t)$ by the formula that Max Alekseyev wrote. It is clearly analytic, and then we can prove by induction that the Taylor coefficients are your numbers $x_n(N)$, and then proceed how he suggested. Or am I misunderstanding some nuance here?

Why worry about analyticity? Can't you just work with $F$ in the ring of formal power series in $z,t$?

No, what I'm saying is to start with a function $F(z, t) = \frac{10}{(11-10z)e^{-10t}-1}$, which I got from connecting to the Cosmos. Then I check by hand that it satisfies the differential equation and has positive radius of uniform convergence in both $z$ and $t$, hence by induction I can prove that it's Taylor coefficients coincide with $x_n(N)$.

What do you mean has potential? Isn't it how we teach children to solve inequalities, say (or at least how I was taught 15 years ago)? Do the algebraic transformations until you reach something positive like a square, then read (and write on the assignment) your proof bottom to top. That's the same idea.

In fact by some theory of differential equations with analytic coefficients I assume we don't even need to know the actual solution to conclude that the radius of convergence is positive.

Ok, I've corrected the expansion and corresponding bound, please check it out.

@MaxAlekseyev: I think it's still not quite right, the last term of the ODE should be $10F/z$, to incorporate the shift to $n+1$ in the index. This may actually be a problem since you want to take $z=0$ later. I've accepted your answer anyway because the general idea is helpful for me and the question is really a toy version of my actual problem anyway, so the fine details are not crucial. Thank you for your help.

@MaxAlekseyev: You can fix it as follows: replace the last term of the recursion by $10(n+1)x_{n+1}(N)/(N+1)$. Obviously, the new sequence bounds the old one. Now your method gives a PDE for $F$ that you can still solve explicitly (or use Cauchy-Kovalevskaya).

@ChristianRemling: Thanks for spotting another glitch, and it's great you figured out how to overcome it. The corrected ODE is also solvable, but it's more technically challenging to extract $F(0,t)$ from it. Anyway, since this particular problem is a toy one, I'll leave my answer as is.
